# Is Promise.all faster than individual await statements when the promises are already running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

Assuming we have two promises, `p1` and `p2`, that we're trying to get their results, `r1` & `r2` respectively. Which of these three options is faster and why, assuming all other things being equal?
To be specific, which option would lead to the console statement running first?

#### Option 1

```js
// Call the async functions first to start the promises.
const p1 = func1();
const p2 = func2();


const r1 = await p1;
const r2 = await p2;

console.log('Done');
```

#### Option 2

```js
// Call the async functions first to start the promises.
const p1 = func1();
const p2 = func2();


const [r1, r2] = await Promise.all([p1, p2]);

console.log('Done');
```

#### Option 3

```js
// Use Promise.all from the beginning:
const [r1, r2] = await Promise.all[func1(), func2()];

console.log('Done');
```

Comment: You still need to `await` the result of `Promise.all`, otherwise it's kind of unfair.

Comment: Measure it and find out.

Comment: @ASDFGerte You're right, I totally forgot. I'll update the question. Thank you!

Comment: The way you answer these kinds of questions is you measure the performance yourself, in your own environment, in the context of your own code.  There are too many variables otherwise.

Comment: Apart from that, you are doing premature optimization. They are so similar, use the one that is the most readable in your opinion.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Option 1 is different from the other two...

Comment: He is calling both functions first, then awaiting the results in a separate step.

Comment: @ASDFGerte oh, you're right!

Comment: @ASDFGerte I agree it's a premature optimization. I'm mainly interested in understanding asynchronous operations in JavaScript better.

Comment: The only time differences you should see are due to differences in execution-time of the different code parts doing the wrap-up. Things like creating the result array vs variables on the environment. Or that in option1, the wrap-up of `p2` will only be done after `p1` resolves, while in the others it can happen beforehand. Maybe in once case, a specific optimization from the engine speeds things up (yay i waited 5 seconds for the promise, and afterwards saved a few microseconds compared to the other code!), but that would be both engine- and version-specific, and nothing you should care about.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple really, you have 2 cases to inspect: `p1` takes longer than `p2` OR `p2` takes longer than `p1`.

**`p1` takes longer than `p2`**

That means that when you first `await p1` you'll do all the waiting there. Reaching `await p2` it'll already be resolved and no waiting would occur.

That means you wait at most `p1` time. In other words, you wait at most for the longest one.

**`p2` takes longer than `p1`**

That means that when you first `await p1` you'll do some of the waiting there. Reaching `await p2` you'll have to wait for the remainder before it's resolved.

That means you wait at most `p2` time. In other words, you wait at most for the longest one.

**await Promise.all([p1, p2])**

The promises are already running, and since `Promise.all` only resolves when every underlying resolves, you'll wait at most for the longest one.

Same goes for `Promise.all([myFuncA(), myFuncB()])`.

**What's the point of `Promise.all` then?**

Well the difference would be with the following code:

```
const r1 = await myFuncA();
const r2 = await myFuncB();
```

Here, unlike with all your examples, the promises are not already running: they're created "on the fly" in the `await` expression.

This means you'll have to wait for `p1 + p2` time instead of `max(p1, p2)` time.

Also, in your examples you only have 2 promises so it's still manageable to split them "manually".

When you have an array of unknown length (e.g. `something.map(...)`) or even just a good chunk of promises to create at once, it's just less fastidious to just put them in `Promise.all`.

Comment: `Promise.all` also makes it easier to handle rejected promises: as soon as either p1 or p2 throws, you can catch the error. Simply wrapping `await p1; await p2` with a `try{} catch() {}` is not the same.

Comment: That is absolutely correct!